# How to call a function with Rowtype parameter from a select statement in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have an oracle function which has an in parameter which is of rowtype of a table, from a select statement i need to pass the current row to this function so that it does some processing and returns a value. Is there a pseudo variable that can be used within the context of a select statement something equivalent to a old and new in trigger.

I would like to do something like

```
select *,function1(rowtype) from table1
```

I want to avoid passing multiple parameters, so the question should be seen in that context.

Answer (score 8):

You can't do this with %ROWTYPE. %ROWTYPE is actually a PL/SQL record type, which is not a legal type in SQL, so you can't use it in a SELECT. You should create an object type which has the same columns as the table, change to function to expect that object type instead of %ROWTYPE, and then you can write something like this:

```
SELECT function(table1_typ(column1, column2, column3))
  FROM table1 t1
```

Drawbacks: You still have to type all the columns in the SELECT, and if you change the table, you will need to change the object type and the SELECT too.

Comment: well i actually was looking for this option since i wanted avoid passing multiple columnns to stored procedure, but if i still need to pass all the columns, i think i am better off passing them to SP then to connvert to a type and then send it.

Comment: As @DineshManne says, this is no better than `SELECT function(column1, column2, column3) FROM table1 t1`, except longer to type. Well, unless you can not change the definition of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass the id of the row in and make the function work on that?

---

EDIT:  You might be able to construct an OBJECT / TYPE on the fly and pass that to a function.  Then you'll only need to query for the data once.  Let me know if you need an example.

---

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
DECLARE
    foo table1%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
     function1(foo);
END;
```

EDIT: You can check out [this blog post](http://itq.nl/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-with-rowtype-inout-parameter-directly-from-code/) for a more detailed description of how to use this technique.

Comment: this needs to be a single select statement, if i go through PL/SQL then i do have many options

Comment: This doesn't answer how to call the function from a select statement.