# Passing actual row as parameter to function (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to pass an actual row as a parameter to a function in oracle. For Example:

I need doing something like this:

```
Select 
   tA.paramA1, 
   tB.paramB1, 
   test_func(tA.*) as calc -- where tA.* is actual row processed.
from tA, tb 
where --joins--;
```

notice that test_func(tA.*) is all row.

I need to make this because the function test_func() need to make several calculations with multiple values of rows of table tA and I don't like to make something like test_func(tA.param1, tA.param2, ...., tA.paramN)

Comment: I don't understand. `tA` is the name of a table or view `FROM` which you select. How is it "the actual row processed"? You say "it is not the table tA" but that is not for you to decide; tA **is** the table. So, you must mean something else. WHAT DO YOU MEAN? What do you mean by "passing a **row** as parameter"?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the function's code. Maybe that can shed some light on it.

Comment: Row means collectively all rowwise record data like a linear row for all columns data needs to be passed

Comment: @mathguy: he probably means something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=751ba451aad428899b8e3a98037c4fee  (but I don't think that is even remotely possible in Oracle)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605925/how-to-call-a-function-with-rowtype-parameter-from-a-select-statement-in-oracle

Comment: @mathguy yes, is passing row as parameter to function. somethhing like this: test_func(tA.*)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a record type parameter plus in order to get that row use below

```
   Procedure(Table%ROWTYPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option.

First, create type which looks like table you'll be passing to a function. As I'm using Scott's sample `EMP` and `DEPT` table, my function will return a string that consists of department number concatenated with department name and location initials.

```
SQL> create or replace type t_dept_r as object
  2    (deptno number, dname varchar2(20), loc varchar2(20));
  3  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace function test_Func(par_dr in t_dept_r)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4    retval varchar2(20);
  5  begin
  6    retval := to_char(par_dr.deptno) ||
  7              substr(par_dr.dname, 1, 1) ||
  8              substr(par_dr.loc, 1, 1);
  9    return retval;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

Let's test it:

```
SQL> select e.deptno, e.ename, d.dname, d.loc,
  2    test_func(t_dept_r(d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc)) result
  3  from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
  4  where e.sal > 2000;

    DEPTNO ENAME      DNAME          LOC           RESULT
---------- ---------- -------------- ------------- ----------
        20 JONES      RESEARCH       DALLAS        20RD
        30 BLAKE      SALES          CHICAGO       30SC
        10 CLARK      ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK      10AN
        20 SCOTT      RESEARCH       DALLAS        20RD
        10 KING       ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK      10AN
        20 FORD       RESEARCH       DALLAS        20RD

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As you can see, it requires a little bit of typing (more than you expected, I presume), which includes naming all columns you're passing (i.e. you can't pass something like `test_func(d.*)`).

See if it helps.